# Try to solve NetworkOnMainThreadException using AsyncTask and Thread, both keep same exception

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, network-programming

I try to create a socket server on the phone, I check [all of the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) used in my case, it keep giving me  NetworkOnMainThreadException. anyone can see where is problem in my case? I try to add the internet permission, using thread and AsyncTask too, I don't know why i cannot make it.

server side code(Asynctask version):

```
package com.example.socketserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OptionalDataException;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ServerFragment extends Fragment {

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket connectionSocket;
    private Button mSentButton;
    private TextView mMessageTextView;
    private EditText mMessagEditText;
    private int counter =1;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream;
    private static String TAG="serverFragment";
    private String message;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate starts");

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //refer a view which wires a layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_server,parent,false);

        mSentButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Sentbutton);
        mMessageTextView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreateView starts");
        mMessageTextView.setText("Waiting for connection\n");
         mMessagEditText=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.Message);

         new connection().execute();
         return v;
    }



    private class connection extends AsyncTask{


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                runServer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }




public void runServer() throws IOException
{
    try {
        serverSocket= new ServerSocket(8080,100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mMessageTextView.append("\nRun Server terminated connection");
    }

    Log.i(TAG,"runServer() starts");
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            waitForConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMessageTextView.append("\nWait terminated connection");
            Log.i(TAG,"\nWait terminated connection "+e.toString());
        }
        try {
            getStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMessageTextView.append("\n GetStream() terminated connection");
            Log.i(TAG,"\n GetStream() terminated connection"+ e.toString());
        }
            try{

            processConnection();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMessageTextView.append("\n processConnection() terminated connection");
            Log.i(TAG,"\n processConnection() terminated connection"+ e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        counter++;
        }


    }

}

private void sentDate(String message)
{
    try {
        outputStream.writeObject("SERVER>>>"+message);
        outputStream.flush();
        mMessageTextView.append("\nSERVER>>>"+ message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void closeConnection() throws IOException {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG,"closeConnection starts");
    mMessageTextView.append("\nTerminating connection\n");

    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    connectionSocket.close();


}

private void processConnection() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    message="Connection successful!";
    sentDate(message);
    Log.i(TAG,"ProcessConnection starts");
    do {
        try {
            message=(String)inputStream.readObject();
        } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            mMessageTextView.append("\n Unknown object type received");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mMessageTextView.append("\n"+ message);
            }
        });



    } while (!message.equals("CLIENT>>> TERMINATE"));
}

private void getStream() throws IOException  {

    outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.flush();
    Log.i(TAG,"getStreams()'s output starts");

    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
    Log.i(TAG,"getStreams()'s input created");
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mMessageTextView.append("\nGot i/O stream \n");
        }
    });


}

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG,"waitForConnection() starts");
    mMessageTextView.setText("Waiting for connection\n");

    try {
        connectionSocket=serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mMessagEditText.append("Connection "+ counter+ " received from : "
            + connectionSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        }
    });
}
    }
}
```

Server side code(Thread version)

```
package com.example.socketserver;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OptionalDataException;
import java.io.StreamCorruptedException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;



public class ServerFragment extends Fragment {

    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    Socket connectionSocket;
    private Button mSentButton;
    private TextView mMessageTextView;
    private EditText mMessagEditText;
    private int counter =1;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream;
    private static String TAG="serverFragment";
    private String message;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate starts");

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //refer a view which wires a layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_server,parent,false);

        mSentButton=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.Sentbutton);
        mMessageTextView=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreateView starts");
        mMessageTextView.setText("Waiting for connection\n");
         mMessagEditText=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.Message);
Thread  thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket= new ServerSocket(8080,100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMessageTextView.append("\nRun Server terminated connection");
        }
        try {
            waitForConnection();
            getStream();
            processConnection();
            closeConnection();
            counter++;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
thread.start();
         //new connection().execute();
         return v;
    }


/*
    private class connection extends AsyncTask{


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                serverSocket= new ServerSocket(8080,100);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mMessageTextView.append("\nRun Server terminated connection");
            }
            try {
                waitForConnection();
                getStream();
                processConnection();
                closeConnection();
                counter++;
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        */


/*
public void runServer() throws IOException
{
    try {
        serverSocket= new ServerSocket(8080,100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mMessageTextView.append("\nRun Server terminated connection");
    }

    Log.i(TAG,"runServer() starts");
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            waitForConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMessageTextView.append("\nWait terminated connection");
            Log.i(TAG,"\nWait terminated connection "+e.toString());
        }
        try {
            getStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMessageTextView.append("\n GetStream() terminated connection");
            Log.i(TAG,"\n GetStream() terminated connection"+ e.toString());
        }
            try{

            processConnection();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            mMessageTextView.append("\n processConnection() terminated connection");
            Log.i(TAG,"\n processConnection() terminated connection"+ e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            closeConnection();
        counter++;
        }


    }

}
*/
private void sentDate(String message)
{
    try {
        outputStream.writeObject("SERVER>>>"+message);
        outputStream.flush();
        mMessageTextView.append("\nSERVER>>>"+ message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void closeConnection() throws IOException {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG,"closeConnection starts");
    mMessageTextView.append("\nTerminating connection\n");

    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
    connectionSocket.close();


}

private void processConnection() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    message="Connection successful!";
    sentDate(message);
    Log.i(TAG,"ProcessConnection starts");
    do {
        try {
            message=(String)inputStream.readObject();
        } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            mMessageTextView.append("\n Unknown object type received");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mMessageTextView.append("\n"+ message);
            }
        });



    } while (!message.equals("CLIENT>>> TERMINATE"));
}

private void getStream() throws IOException  {

    outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    outputStream.flush();
    Log.i(TAG,"getStreams()'s output starts");

    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
    Log.i(TAG,"getStreams()'s input created");
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mMessageTextView.append("\nGot i/O stream \n");
        }
    });


}

private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(TAG,"waitForConnection() starts");
    mMessageTextView.setText("Waiting for connection\n");

    try {
        connectionSocket=serverSocket.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mMessagEditText.append("Connection "+ counter+ " received from : "
            + connectionSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        }
    });
}
    }
```

error(AsyncTask version):

```
    08-22 16:35:05.829: I/serverFragment(22134): onCreate starts
    08-22 16:35:05.839: I/serverFragment(22134): onCreateView starts
    08-22 16:35:05.839: I/serverFragment(22134): runServer() starts
    08-22 16:35:05.839: I/serverFragment(22134): waitForConnection() starts
    08-22 16:35:05.889: I/Adreno-EGL(22134): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
    08-22 16:35:05.940: D/OpenGLRenderer(22134): Enabling debug mode 0
    08-22 16:35:13.027: D/AndroidRuntime(22134): Shutting down VM
    08-22 16:35:13.027: W/dalvikvm(22134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415dcba8)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: I/serverFragment(22134): getStreams()'s output starts
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134): Process: com.example.socketserver, PID: 22134
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostByAddrImpl(InetAddress.java:438)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:307)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.example.socketserver.ServerFragment$connection$3.run(ServerFragment.java:216)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    08-22 16:35:13.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    0

8-22 16:40:13.167: I/Process(22134): Sending signal. PID: 22134 SIG: 9
```

error (thread version):

```
ERROR:
08-22 16:28:30.488: I/serverFragment(20568): onCreate starts
08-22 16:28:30.498: I/serverFragment(20568): onCreateView starts
08-22 16:28:30.498: I/serverFragment(20568): waitForConnection() starts
08-22 16:28:30.548: I/Adreno-EGL(20568): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
08-22 16:28:30.588: D/OpenGLRenderer(20568): Enabling debug mode 0
08-22 16:28:38.836: D/AndroidRuntime(20568): Shutting down VM
08-22 16:28:38.836: W/dalvikvm(20568): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415dcba8)
08-22 16:28:38.836: I/serverFragment(20568): getStreams()'s output starts
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568): Process: com.example.socketserver, PID: 20568
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostByAddrImpl(InetAddress.java:438)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:307)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.example.socketserver.ServerFragment$4.run(ServerFragment.java:248)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-22 16:28:38.836: E/AndroidRuntime(20568):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 16:32:37.431: I/Process(20568): Sending signal. PID: 20568 SIG
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `getHostName()` on the main application thread, from the `Runnable` you are passing to `runOnUiThread()`. You need to retrieve the host name from the background thread.